# Resources on designing query languages

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, language-design, domain-specific-languages

I'm looking for resources (books, papers, tutorials) on designing domain-specific query languages. I'm mostly interested in the design of syntax and grammar, rather than the implementation. Any UX-focused resources on designing general-purpose programming languages and text-based UIs would also be of some help. I tried many different queries, but mu Google-fu fails me, so I would be grateful for any resources that touch on this subject.

Comment: Syntax and grammar are definitely going to depend on the target audience; e.g. if they are from a database you'll want to mimic SQL, R for statistics, etc. What's the audience you're aiming for?

Comment: @cody I'm looking for general resources for a broader review if possible.